# How does one prove that the definite integral of a function is unique?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

How would I go about proving that the definite integral is unique?

The problem statement is: Show that the number $I$ in the statement of Theorem 8.1 is unique; that is that there cannot be two numbers that would be assigned to the symbol $\int_a^bf(x)dx.$

**Theorem 8.1 (Cauchy)** *Let $f$ be continuous function on an interval [a,b]. Then there is a number $I$, called the* definite integral *of f on [a,b], such that for each $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ so that*
$$\Bigg|\sum_{k=1}^nf(\zeta_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})-I\Bigg|<\varepsilon$$

Here is my attempt:
**Proof by Contradiction:**
    Assume not; that is, assume there exists more than one $I,$ call them $I_1, I_2$, that are the definite integrals of $f$ (a continuous function on an interval $[a,b]$) on $[a,b]$ such that $\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists\delta>0$ such that 
    $$\Bigg|\sum_{k=1}^nf(\zeta_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})-I_1\Bigg|<\varepsilon$$
    and 
     $$\Bigg|\sum_{k=1}^nf(\zeta_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})-I_2\Bigg|<\varepsilon$$
Without loss of generality, let $I_1<I_2$. Then 
 $$\Bigg|\sum_{k=1}^nf(\zeta_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})-I_1\Bigg|< \Bigg|\sum_{k=1}^nf(\zeta_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})-I_2\Bigg|$$

Choose $\varepsilon$ to be between $\Bigg(\Bigg|\sum_{k=1}^nf(\zeta_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})-I_2\Bigg|-\Bigg|\sum_{k=1}^nf(\zeta_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})-I_1\Bigg|\Bigg)/2$ and $0$. Now $\varepsilon < \Bigg|\sum_{k=1}^nf(\zeta_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})-I_2\Bigg|$

Thus we have a contradiction.

My issue with this proof is that couldn't one just find a different $\delta$ that worked for $I_2$ if it didn't work with both $I_1$ and $I_2$? My proof doesn't use $\delta$ at all.

Comment: it is unique because is a limit. If the limit converges then it value is unique, by the properties of limits of sequences

Comment: The inequality on the line after $I_!\lt I_2$ is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

$|\sum-I_1|\lt \epsilon$ and $|\sum-I_2|\lt \epsilon$ can be combined to get $|(\sum-I_1)-(\sum-I_2)|\lt 2\epsilon$ or $|I_1-I_2|\lt 2\epsilon$, implying $I_1=I_2$.